# Dynamically set property of Object in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I do this...

`var Object."a" = 3;`

Something like this?

`setPropertyOfObjectWith(myObjekt:Object,probname:String,value);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj["something"] = 12;
```